# Integral of complex number over a contour

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

I have
$$\int_{-1}^1 |z|dz$$

I need to calculate the integral where the integration contour is the upper semi-circle with unit radius. I calculated the integral in $(-1; 1)$ section; the answer is 1, but I'm not sure how to calculate for the upper semi-circle.

Comment: What is the upper semi-sphere? We're on a *plane* here.

Comment: Are you looking for $\int\limits_\gamma |z| dz$ where $\gamma$ is semicircle in the upper half-plane?

Comment: Do you mean semi circle?

Comment: Yes, sorry, semi circle. Will update the post now. @Josh, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I think I may have been considering a different contour, since the original poster asked what they could do after finding $\int\limits_{-1}^1 |z|dz$. I am thinking of a contour like this: [image]

where $R=1$. If OP only requires the upper half, then we can disregard the $1$ in the final sum.

If you're taking $\gamma$ to be this contour, note that $\gamma$ is formed by two curves: $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ where $\gamma_1$ is the interval $[-1,1]$ and $\gamma_2$ is the upper arc of the semicircle. Thus we have that $$ \int\limits_\gamma |z| dz = \int\limits_{\gamma_1} |z|dz + \int\limits_{\gamma_2}|z|dz$$
You already found that  $$ \int\limits_{\gamma_1} |z|dz = \int\limits_{-1}^1 |z| dz = 1$$
We have to find $\int\limits_{\gamma_2}|z|dz$. Note that for all $z$ on $\gamma_2$, $|z|=1$ because $z$ lies on the arc of the unit circle. So \begin{align*}\int\limits_{\gamma_2}|z|dz = \int\limits_{\gamma_2}1dz = \int\limits_0^\pi ie^{i\theta}d\theta = -2
\end{align*}
 So $$ \int\limits_\gamma |z| dz = -1$$

Comment: That's the contour I meant.

Comment: Apologies, I made a dumb error, let me fix that

Comment: I just don't understand how you get the π. Isn't $\int_{\gamma}1dz=z$, which is just 1?

Answer (score 0):

Are you integrating clockwise or anti-clockwise?

Assuming you're integrating anti-clockwise, use a substitution of $z=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta}$, where $0 \le \theta \le \pi$.

It follows that $\mathrm dz = \mathrm{ie}^{\mathrm i \theta}~\mathrm d\theta$.

Hence $$\int_C |z|~\mathrm dz = \int_0^{\pi} |\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \theta}| ~\mathrm{ie}^{\mathrm i \theta}~\mathrm d\theta = \mathrm i\int_0^{\pi}\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}~\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: Given that the original integral is $\int_{-1}^1$, I suspect the semicircle is actually supposed to be parametrized clockwise. (Also because your parametrization gives an answer of $-2$.)

Comment: @André3000 I'm not sure. It's not clear from the OP. Most students, when integrating along the real line, have the lower limit less than the upper limit. (They don't realise that we're integrating along an oriented path.)